# Why is my app requesting permission to find and use accounts?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-permissions, flurry, android-account

I'm trying to incorporate analytics (Flurry) for the first time and I had to add the following permissions to my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

When I signed the app and installed it on my phone to test, I was prompted to allow the following additional permissions:

> approximate location (network-based)
>
> find accounts on the device
>   use accounts on the device
>
> full network access view network connections

I understand the first and last, but **why is my app requested access to accounts?**  Is this something because of Flurry or because I had to incorporate Google Play Services?

I pride my app in being a very lightweight utility and I already dislike the increased package size and inclusion of the Internet permission. I really don't like the idea of shipping my app with access to accounts, which has no use in my actual app.

Does anybody know what this is about? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use some external libraries (e.g. aar) that might include the permission?

Comment: Are those the only permissions in your manifest?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642287/user-gets-permissions-request-that-are-not-included-in-the-manifest/30642755#30642755